# Viewing PWA - No "Add to homescreen" button CHROME

Tags: java, visual-studio, google-chrome, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

[image: Here is a snapshot]

The service worker and manifest have no errors... Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. 
Is there a similar way to achieve the "Add to Homescreen" in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Is there a similar way to achieve the "add to homescreen" in microsoft edge?

Comment: Please don't add edits in the comments section: just edit your question.

Comment: I think it is there? See the little plus with the circle around it in the address bar? When you first get to the page it also says "Install", but that slides over after a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome changed the way to install a PWA manually. Now you can click the "+" icon in the address bar (as suggested by Mathias).

Alternatively you can expand the Chrome menu (three dots on the top right) and select "Install AppName" (where AppName is the name of the web site where you currently are).

There isn't anymore an "install" link in the Application Tab (the Chrome documentation has not been updated about this part yet).

[image]